# How to push other divs down?

Tags: html, css, smartbanner

I am making my own smart banner, and Everything is working fine including the js code. The idea is that when a user opens the website on their mobile device, a banner drops down from the top asking if he/she wants to download. However,when my smartbanner drops down from the top, it just overlaps the other div below it, instead of pushing it down. here is my css code. The div below is a sticky header, thus its position is fixed.

```
#smartbanner .smartbanner-button { 
        position:absolute; 
        right:20px; 
        top:24px; 
        border:1px solid #bfbfbf; 
        padding: 0 10px; 
        min-width: 10%; 
        height:24px; 
        font-size:14px; 
        line-height:24px; 
        text-align:center; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        color:white; 
    }
    #smartbanner { 
        position:absolute; 
        left:0;
        border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8; 
        width:100%; 
        height:78px;
        top: -80px;
        transition: top 300ms;
        opacity: 0.95;
        background: rgba(250,250,250,1);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 47%, rgba(232,232,232,1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(250,250,250,1)), color-stop(47%, rgba(240,240,240,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(232,232,232,1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 47%, rgba(232,232,232,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 47%, rgba(232,232,232,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 47%, rgba(232,232,232,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(250,250,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 47%, rgba(232,232,232,1) 100%);
    }
    #smartbanner .smartbanner-close{
        margin-left: 0.1em;
        margin-top: 1.5em;
        font-size: 1em;
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }
    #smartbanner .smartbanner-logo { 
        position:absolute; 
        left:30px; 
        top:10px; 
        display:block; 
        width:57px; 
        height:57px; 
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        background-size:cover; 
        border-radius:10px; 
        box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    }
    #smartbanner .smartbanner-info { 
        position:absolute; 
        left:103px; 
        top:10px; 
        width:44%; 
        font-size:11px;
        line-height:0.2em;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#6a6a6a;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8); 
    }
    #smartbanner .smartbanner-price { 
        position:absolute; 
        left:103px; 
        top:30px; 
        width:44%; 
        font-size:11px;
        line-height:0.2em;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#6a6a6a;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8); 
    }
    #smartbanner .smartbanner-info strong {
        display:block; 
        font-size:13px;
        color:#4d4d4d; 
        line-height: 18px; 
    }
    #smartbanner .smartbanner-input {
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }
```

Comment: Off topic: [dont do that on the internet](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/most-hated-advertising-techniques/).

Comment: I understand, but Its for my work haha. They are trying to increase app downloads.

Comment: You may carefully point them to this link. Good luck :-)

Comment: Regarding your problem: It is probably because you work with `position:absolute`, this takes the element out of the flow with other elements. Try out `position:relative`.

Comment: If you want to stick to `position:absolute` make the other element a child element of your banner. Other solutions are not possible with raw CSS.

Comment: Don't use position absolute, it's very inflexible.

Comment: I still cant figure it out, but Thanks anyways! :D

Comment: @hungerstar what do you recommend me to do?